# StringBuilder to XMLNode

Tags: .net, xslt

I have an `XslCompiledTransform` object that I use to transform an XML fragment. The transformation works right and outputs the new content to a `StringBuilder` object.

What is the best way to create a new `XmlNode` with the `StringBuilder` content?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); <-- This is an XmlNode
doc.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
```

should do it.